# Asp.net DropDownList not binding inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, data-binding

I need to bind an Asp.net DropDownList inside an ItemTemplate of a ListView. I am using LINQ to query data from using the LINQ db context as follow:

.cs

```
protected void ListView_AllTickets_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    DropDownList ddl_spList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList_SpList");

    //Getting all service providers users
    var spusers = (from x in db.User1s where x.usertype == "200" select x);

    ddl_spList.DataSource = spusers;

    ddl_spList.DataTextField = "email";

    ListView_AllTickets.DataBind();

}
```

.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_SpList" runat="server" class="form-control" ClientIDMode="AutoID"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Notice how I am finding the control then binding it to the result of the LINQ query. When I use the debugger, the data is retrieved successfully and the "email" field exists in the returned data. However, and for some reason, the ListView_AllTickets will have an item count of 0 even after the DataBind() statment.

Comment: Try ddl_spList.DataBind() maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add this line:

```
 ddl_spList.DataBind();
```

You're rebinding `ListView_AllTickets`, but that's the parent object and is already being bound (hence the event you're handling with this method).  Is that a typo?

Bind `ddl_spList` instead.

Comment: Oh gosh! I spent half a day trying to figure out whats wrong with my code.